# Accessing an HttpServletRequest from inside an AXIS2 module

Tags: apache-axis, axis

I am implementing AXIS2 services in my web application.  Our client's production boxes are a bit flaky, so I want a heads up when performance degraded.  Specifically:

- request comes into my AXIS2 service
- measure the time that the request takes
- if the time is greater than X, log an error

So I wrote an AXIS2 module like this:

```
public class PerformanceHandler extends AbstractHandler implements Handler {
protected Logger logger = null;

public PerformanceHandler() {
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( this.getClass() );
}

public InvocationResponse invoke( MessageContext msgContext ) throws AxisFault {
    HttpServletRequest r = ( HttpServletRequest )msgContext.getProperty( HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST );
    if( msgContext.getFLOW() == MessageContext.IN_FLOW || msgContext.getFLOW() == MessageContext.IN_FAULT_FLOW ) {
        // incoming request
        Date timeIn = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        r.setAttribute( this.getClass().getName() + ".timeIn", timeIn );
        if( logger.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            logger.debug( "Request " + r.toString()  + " started processing at " + timeIn );
        }
    } else {
        // outgoing response
        Date timeIn = ( Date )r.getAttribute( this.getClass().getName() + ".timeIn" );
        Date timeOut = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        if( logger.isDebugEnabled() ) {
            logger.debug( "Request " + r.toString()  + " finished processing at " + timeOut );
        }
        long delta = timeOut.getTime() - timeIn.getTime();
        if( delta > 300 ) { // todo: parameterize the delta threshold
            logger.error( "Request " + r.toString() + " took " + delta + "ms to process." );
        }
    }

    return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
}
}
```

After that, I edited the module.xml, axis2.xml appropriately, created the *.mar file and ran the app.

However, it seems that

```
HttpServletRequest r = ( HttpServletRequest )msgContext.getProperty( HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST )
```

is null.  That was unexpected.

So my questions are:

- How can I access the servlet request in an AXIS2 module?
- If this is not allowed, what's the alternative for me to track the time between request starting processing and ending processing?
- I should be using some other existing AXIS2 functionality that can give me the same kind of result?

Many thanks in advance,
Dave C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `HttpServletRequest`, you should use the `OperationContext` (which you can get from the `MessageContext` using the `getOperationContext` method) to store the timestamp of the request. The operation context is the same for an incoming request and the corresponding response.

Comment: At the end, I ended up writing a javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener instead.

But it's good to know what the OperationContext is for; will definitely use it in the future.